# Android BluetoothGatt discover services not discovering updated services after services changed in paired device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am building a Flutter application which uses bluetooth to communicate with STM32 Microcontroller (device). There are two binaries using BLE stack in microcontrollers with different Gatt profile.

- Normal (application) binary with different services UUIDs
- Firmware Update binary with only OTA service UUIDs

When device is running normal binary, Firmware update service and characteristics are hidden or unavailable and when device is in firmware update mode normal services and characteristics are hidden.
Device is paired/bonded with android app. When I switch mode from normal to firmware update or vice versa, the device reboots and android Gatt discover services is called again.
The Problem is android cache the services and characteristics at the time of pairing/bonding and when I switch mode from Normal to Firmware Update, I am getting cached services and characteristics instead of changed services.

I want to know how to reset this cache and get updated services and characteristics on Android side?

Things I tried

- Calling private refresh method in BluetoothGatt, Not possible in current version
- Executing BluetoothGatt.disconnect() -> BluetoothGatt.close() -> Setting BluetoothGatt Null -> Calling connect gatt again
- Listening to “Service Changed” Characteristic in “Generic Attribute” Service by setting characteristics notification true and setting CCC Descriptor value

Comment: The "Service Changed" indication is the correct method according to the Bluetooth standard to detect changed services. You can also use the "Database Hash" characteristic (relatively new feature). Are you sure the peripheral actually sends a correct Service Changed indication to the central, after it has changed its services? Generally, for best user experience and to avoid abruptions, I would however recommend implementing the firmware update feature directly in the main binary.